# "de manière simple" or "d'une manière simple"

Tags: articles

"He lives in a simple manner/way."

Should the translation be

> Il vit de manière/façon simple.

or

> Il vit d'**une** manière/façon simple.

I think I've seen *manière* and *façon* used both with and without *une*, so I'm not sure which one is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say:

> Il vit de manière simple.

It's not expected that you give more detail about the way he is living. What is important here is "Il".

Whith:

> Il vit d'une manière simple.

You mention that his way of living has something special. It's expected that more details about this way of living will come up.

Some examples:

> Il vit de manière simple car il est très pauvre.
>
> Il vit d'une manière simple: il ne mange que de la soupe et fait ses courses à pied.